# Replacing kitchen faucet, unsure how to remove old plate holding hoses

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I'm replacing my kitchen faucet and ran into an issue taking out the old Kohler faucet. Pictures of the problem at the bottom.

Underneath the sink there's two overlapping plates holding in the hot and cold hoses and the hose that was running to the separate sprayer. Those plates had two screws in them, but taking those out didn't seem to do much -- not sure if they just stuck together over time, but I couldn't manage to pry them apart either.

It looks like one of the hoses has a nut towards the top, but with the other hoses so close, I can't get it with a wrench or pliers. I'm not even sure a basin wrench could get to it, but I've never used one before.

Does this seem to be a case for a basin wrench, or am I missing something else with removing these plates?

Picture 1: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtP1J.jpg]
Picture 2: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXDOw.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the threaded tube? There's a nut threaded on that, which holds the plate in place.

Use a [Basin Wrench](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21N6ecTUeOL.jpg) (or any wrench you can fit in there) to loosen the nut (rotate the nut anticlockwise to loosen it), and the plate will slide out.

[image]

If the nut is stubborn, and doesn't want to budge. A good shot of penetrating oil can loosen things up.